# pythonic way to customize classes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to figure out a clean way to use inheritance for custom classes. I have the following directory structure.

```
inheritTest.py
Level1
    __init__.py
    t_Generic.py
Level2
    __init__.py
    t_Custom.py
```

**Goal:** I want all the classes of t_Generic accessible by importing t_Custom module and allow needed customization in t_Custom.

There is nothing in two of the **init**.py files above.

t_Generic.py contains some generic classes like these:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = "Hello! I am Mr.A from t_generic"
    def someOtherMethod(self):
        pass

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = "Hello! I am Mr.B from t_generic"
    def someOtherMethod(self):
        pass

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = "Hello! I am Mr.C from t_generic"
    def changeHello(self):
        pass
```

Experimental t_Custom.py is as below:

```
import Level1.t_Generic

#Override any Generic classes in this module.

#Option 1: Let's get Generic A so it lives in this scope as A
from Level1.t_Generic import A

#Option 2: Let's create B and inherit from Generic, make future custom changes here
class B(Level1.t_Generic.B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B,self).__init__()


#I really want to inherit from C and change it's behavior
class C(Level1.t_Generic.C):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C,self).__init__()
    def changeHello(self):
        self.hello = "Hello! I am Mr.C modified in t_Custom"
```

**Question:** What's the pythonic way to do something like this? Should I just import all the generic classes in Custom module as in option 1 or should I create an inherited class in Custom as in Option 2 and modify the ones I want to inherit from?

Example use case in inheritTest.py:

```
import Level2.t_Custom

a = Level2.t_Custom.A()
b = Level2.t_Custom.B()
c = Level2.t_Custom.C()

print a.hello
print b.hello
print c.hello
c.changeHello()
print c.hello
```

output:

```
Hello! I am Mr.A from t_generic
Hello! I am Mr.B from t_generic
Hello! I am Mr.C from t_generic
Hello! I am Mr.C modified in t_Custom
```

Comment: How exactly do you intend to use this setup? With a toy example as you've provided it's hard to tell whether there's a better way. Must the custom classes have the same name as the generic ones? Will there be multiple "custom" override modules? How do you decide when to use generic vs custom? Can mix-ins be considered as an alternative?

Comment: @tzaman, (1)Yes, generic and custom must have the same names. (2)There will be multiple custom override modules but they will all inherit from generic and do not step on each other. (3)Custom is generally used based on some arguments, if no matching custom module  for the arguments it will directly import the generic modules and uses them. So in this case I will wrap the imports in a condition or try/catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I haven't tested this, but I think it should do what you want. Consider it whiteboard code*

First, you need to use relative imports in t_Custom.py then import the generic classes

```
from ..Level1 import t_Generic
from t_Generic import A as GenericA
from t_Generic import B as GenericB
from t_Generic import C as GenericC
```

I rename the classes to avoid any clashes in your module's namespace.

Now, to get your desired output, in t_Custom.py (copying your original code)

```
A = GenericA # Just re-export the generic A class

class B(GenericB):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B,self).__init__()

#I really want to inherit from C and change it's behavior
class C(GenericC):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C,self).__init__()
    def changeHello(self):
        self.hello = "Hello! I am Mr.C modified in t_Custom"
```

and then, to try and avoid exporting t_Generic.A etc from your module

```
__all__ = ["A","B","C"]
```

As Alex mentioned in his comment, it is generally considered a "Bad Thing" (TM) to pointlessly override a method of a base class. Only do that if you want to modify or add behavior. Then t_Custom.py becomes more like this:

```
from ..Level1 import t_Generic
from t_Generic import A as GenericA
from t_Generic import B as GenericB
from t_Generic import C as GenericC

A = GenericA # Just re-export the generic A class
B = GenericB # I'll subclass when I know what I want to do to it

#I really want to inherit from C and change it's behavior
class C(GenericC):
    def changeHello(self):
        self.hello = "Hello! I am Mr.C modified in t_Custom"

__all__ = ["A","B","C"]
```

Comment: **Please** lose the totally useless `def __init__(self): super(B,self).__init__()`.  **NEVER** override any method, `__init__` included, to do nothing but delegate to the superclass -- **what's the point**?!

Comment: Wouldn't have done it myself, I was just copying the OP's structure for clarity. I agree with you wholeheartedly on not overriding in that case

Comment: So please edit your A to give the good example (and maybe add the explanation of it)?  Pretty please with a CherryPy on top?

Comment: If we do "class B(Level1.t_Generic.B): pass" we don't need to mess with renaming and again pointing it old name as in your answer. Is there any known pythonic reasoning to pick one over the other?

Comment: The renaming means that t_Custom never has both `t_Generic.A` and `A` in its `__dict__`, and just avoids any unpleasant surprises from typos. As to `A=GenericA` versus `class A(GenericA): pass`, I think the former (a) is slightly more efficient, and (b) expresses the equivalence more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question depends on how many classes you want in the scope of `Level2.t_Custom`. In general it's best to only import the objects into a module's scope that you're actually going to use. This keeps the scope clean and organised.

But if the module is intended to be used elsewhere then it may be necessary to import all objects from `Level1.t_Generic` into the scope and add your custom classes. For example, if someone else (or you yourself) will only import from `Level2.t_Custom` then it really depends on what you wish to expose there.

Comment: Yes, I may import from Level2.t_Custom as well and I would like to expose all the classes of Level1.t_Generic in Level2.t_Custom. Given this case, is your suggestion "from Level1.t_Generic import *" and then customize the needed ones?

Comment: Then you really need to use different class names in t_Custom.py.

Comment: I think @kdopen's answer works best as it imports the generic classes with a different name so you decide how you expose them.